# BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type TrackingBloc

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm trying to provide a `TrackingBloc` to `MapScreen` but when sending an event from `onPressed` I get the error `BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type TrackingBloc.` 
`MapScreen` also uses a `MapBloc` provided from `main()`, but for `TrackingBloc` I want to make it local, not to clutter `MultiBlocProvider`in `main()`. 
I tried:

1. To use the `bloc:` parameter in the `BlocListener<TrackingBloc, TrackingState>`, as I've been told that it just provides the bloc as a `BlocProvider` would(https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/930#issuecomment-593790702) but it didn't work.
2. Then I tried making `MultiBlocLister` a child of a `MultiBlocProvider` and set `TrackingBloc` there, but still get the message.
3. Set `TrackingBloc`in the `MultiBlocProvider` in `main() and worked as expected.

Why 1 and 2 don't provide `TrackingBloc`to the tree? 
Many thanks for your help.

MapScreen:

```
class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  final MapRepository _mapRepository;

  MapScreen(
      {Key key, @required this.name, @required MapRepository mapRepository})
      : assert(mapRepository != null),
        _mapRepository = mapRepository,
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  List<Marker> alerts;
  LatLng userLocation;

  MapController _mapController = MapController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<TrackingBloc>(create: (context) {
          return TrackingBloc();
        }),
      ],
      child: MultiBlocListener(
        listeners: [
          BlocListener<MapBloc, MapState>(
              listener: (BuildContext context, MapState state) {
            if (state is LocationStream) {
              setState(() {
                userLocation = (state).location;
//              print(
//                  ' @@@@ MapBloc actual user location from stream  is : $userLocation');
              });
            }
            if (state is MapCenter) {
              userLocation = (state).location;
//            print(' @@@@ MapBloc initial center location is : $userLocation');
              _mapController.move(userLocation, 16);
            }
          }),
          BlocListener<TrackingBloc, TrackingState>(
//              bloc: TrackingBloc(),
              listener: (BuildContext context, TrackingState state) {
            if (state is TrackedRoute) {
              List<Position> route = (state).trackedRoute;
              print(route);
            }
          }),
        ],
        child: Scaffold(
```

main():

```
  runApp(
    MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
          create: (context) {
            return AuthenticationBloc(
              userRepository: UserRepository(),
            )..add(AppStarted());
          },
        ),
        BlocProvider<MapBloc>(create: (context) {
          return MapBloc(
            mapRepository: mapRepository,
          )
            ..add(GetLocationStream())
            ..add(GetLocation());
        }),
        BlocProvider<TrackingBloc>(create: (context) {
          return TrackingBloc();
        }),
//        BlocProvider<AlertBloc>(create: (context) {
//          return AlertBloc(
//            alertRepository: alertRepository,
//          )..add(LoadAlerts());
//        }),
      ],
      child:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right of the bat, I can see two things are wrong with your code.

**First:** You provide multiple TrackingBloc, in main and MapScreen.

**Second:** You are accessing TrackingBloc via BlocListener within the same context where you provide it (the second `BlocProvider(create: (context) {return TrackingBloc();})`). My guess is this is what causing the error.

> BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type TrackingBloc

I think by simply removing BlocProvider in the MapScreen will do the job.

Comment: Jonathan. I actually find the right place to provide `TrackingBloc`and I'll put it in the answer to my question, but let me explain a bit what the confusion was.
I  want provide `TrackingBloc` to `MapScreen` because I want it to be available only to that screen. So first I tried pass it in the `bloc:` parameter of the `BlocListener`, mislead from the comment I linked. 
That didn't provide `TrackingBloc` as I was expecting, so I tried providing it directly in `MapScreen` but of course (now I know) that didn't provide the bloc either.

Still providing it globally obviously worked.

Comment: So the solution was to provide `TrackingBloc` in the state check I do on `AuthenticationState`and from which I return the various screens including `MapScreen`(see solution).

So what I'm left wandering is what `bloc:` parameter of both `BlocBuilder`and `BlocListener` really is. Are they an entry point to the widget three for a new bloc as I was told in the linked comment(which now doesn't seem like to be...), and I just didn't write the right code to implement it correctly, or is just (as it would make more sense to be..) a reference to a certain bloc?

Comment: I was not aware with that bloc property in BlocBuilder and BlocListener. After reading it I am not so sure what it really does either.

Comment: Jonathan I opened a new issue so we'll see what Felix will answer.
https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/943 
Thank you for your help on this one too.

Answer (score 0):

I was providing `TrackingBloc`from the wrong place in the widget tree.
I can provide the bloc globally which I don't need, so to provide it locally as I want, I  have to provide it from `Blocbuilder`in `main()` which is returning `MapScreen`.

Changing `main()` from:

```
    return MaterialApp(
      home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is Unauthenticated) {
            return LoginScreen(userRepository: _userRepository);
          }
          if (state is Authenticated) {
//            BlocProvider.of<MapBloc>(context).add(GetLocationStream());
//            BlocProvider.of<AlertBloc>(context).add(LoadAlerts());
            return MapScreen(
              mapRepository: _mapRepository,
              name: state.displayName,
//              alertRepository: FirebaseAlertRepository(),
            );
          }
          if (state is Unauthenticated) {
            return LoginScreen(userRepository: _userRepository);
          }
          return SplashScreen();
        },
      ),
    );
```

to:

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is Unauthenticated) {
            return LoginScreen(userRepository: _userRepository);
          }
          if (state is Authenticated) {
//            BlocProvider.of<MapBloc>(context).add(GetLocationStream());
//            BlocProvider.of<AlertBloc>(context).add(LoadAlerts());
            return MultiBlocProvider(
              providers: [
                BlocProvider<TrackingBloc>(create: (context) {
                  return TrackingBloc();
                }),
              ],
              child: MapScreen(
                mapRepository: _mapRepository,
                name: state.displayName,
//              alertRepository: FirebaseAlertRepository(),
              ),
            );
            return MapScreen(
              mapRepository: _mapRepository,
              name: state.displayName,
//              alertRepository: FirebaseAlertRepository(),
            );
          }
          if (state is Unauthenticated) {
            return LoginScreen(userRepository: _userRepository);
          }
          return SplashScreen();
        },
      ),
    );
```

makes it work as I intended. 
Then in `MapScreen` I just use different `BlocListener` to listen to blocs being  global as `MapBloc`  or local as `TrackingBloc` :

```
class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  List<Marker> alerts;
  LatLng userLocation;

  MapController _mapController = MapController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocListener(
      listeners: [
        BlocListener<MapBloc, MapState>(
            listener: (BuildContext context, MapState state) {
          if (state is LocationStream) {
            setState(() {
              userLocation = (state).location;
//              print(
//                  ' @@@@ MapBloc actual user location from stream  is : $userLocation');
            });
          }
          if (state is MapCenter) {
            userLocation = (state).location;
//            print(' @@@@ MapBloc initial center location is : $userLocation');
            _mapController.move(userLocation, 16);
          }
        }),
        BlocListener<TrackingBloc, TrackingState>(
//              bloc: TrackingBloc(),
            listener: (BuildContext context, TrackingState state) {
//      userLocation = (state as LocationStream).location;
          if (state is TrackedRoute) {
            List<Position> route = (state).trackedRoute;
            print(route);
//            initialLocation = (state).location.then((value) {
//              print('@@@@@@ value is : $value');
////              _mapController.move(value, 16.0);
//              return value;
//            }
//            );
          }
        }),
      ],
      child: Scaffold(
```

Hope this will help others just starting out with `flutter_bloc` that might not find documentation usage explanation of its widgets clearly enough.
Still have to fully understand `BlocProvider`'s and `BlocListener`'s `bloc:` property dough..
Cheers.